# Bootstrap column that goes beyond end of screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

this is my first post here. I am trying to do something like this: https://bravepeople.co where the last image in the column is half way off the screen. However I am having trouble figuring out how to do it with Bootstrap.

Here is my code:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-N415hCJJdJx+1UBfULt+i+ihvOn42V/kOjOpp1UTh4CZ70Hx5bDlKryWaqEKfY/8EYOu/C2MuyaluJryK1Lb5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

```html
<div class="container-md">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <h2>Title!</h2>
  <p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
    accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab
    illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt
    explicabo.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/354x580" height="580px" width="354px" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/354x580" height="580px" width="354px" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/354x580" height="580px" width="354px" />
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I add an other column but have it cut off at the very end of the screen? Thanks

Comment: Just on a glance I can see that you use 4 columns with the size of 4 (`col-lg-4 col-md-4`) in 1 `row`. A row always has the size of 12 columns and yours add up to 16.

Comment: `.row` class applies `flex-flow: wrap` which will wrap down flex-children in the next line. So to begin with - add `flex-nowrap` to your row div, make `overflow-x: hidden` and play with image min-width to attain the layout.

Comment: @slumbergeist can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd remove the image containing div out of the normal flow by positioning it either `absolute` or `fixed`.

I've made the main parent container `position:relative` and wrapped all the images in a container div which is `position:absolute` with respect to the parent. You can use `px or %` unit to position your images easily now.

Since, the div is using absolute positioning it is no longer part of the normal document flow and will be painted in another layer. Hence, not causing any unintended overflows or content wrapping.

```css
.img-container {
   right: -45px;
   top: 10%;
}

.img-container_image {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main>
  <section class="row position-relative vw-100 vh-100 m-0 p-0 bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-light">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <aside class="row flex-nowrap p-0 position-absolute img-container col-8 h-50">
      <div class="bg-secondary col-4 p-0 ms-1">
        <img class="width-100 h-100 img-container_image "/>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-primary col-4 p-0 ms-1">
        <img class="width-100 h-100 img-container_image "/>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-success col-4 p-0 ms-1">
        <img class="width-100 h-100 img-container_image "/>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Yeah but this isn't responsive, and when I try to make it responsive by changing col-4 to col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 it doesn't work at all

Comment: yes, that's because the image container is absolutely positioned. You have to write media query to position it relatively on the breakpoint you want. Also, change the direction of flex if you want to stack images vertically after hitting a certain breakpoint. Bootstrap like libraries are just a convenience, you can't rely solely on them. I'd suggest you to try first once